# How to install a 32bit gcc compiler on a X86_64 CentOS system

Tags: linux, gcc, centos

I have tried the following command:

```
yum install libgcc.i686  --setopt=protected_multilib=false
```

But I got some error message from the output:

```
Transaction Check Error:
  package libgcc-4.8.2-8.el6.x86_64 (which is newer than libgcc-4.4.7-18.el6_9.2.i686) is already installed
```

So how to fix this issue? I think it's acceptable to keep both two arch version compilers in the system.

Comment: if you have nothing to do with libgcc-4.8.2-8.el6.x86_64 (new one), then try removing it and then install old one.

Comment: I need to keep the current one and the old one just for temporary use.

Comment: if it centos 6 then you must be having both the packages already. Kindly check using rpm -qa

Answer (score 2):

You may need to instal `i686` components of GCC:

```
yum install libgcc.i686 glibc-devel.i686
```

For C++ you will also need

```
yum install libstdc++-devel.i686
```

Comment: Perfect answer!

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you that the x86 and x86_64 version of the libraries must be in sync, so you'll need to install/update both:

```
yum install libgcc libgcc.i686
```